# Instagram discord bot not working - problem with environmental variables?

Tags: python, discord, instagram

I wanted to make a bot for discord that would send a notification when a user has uploaded on instagram. I’m not good at coding so I found a python code on GitHub, however when I try to run it it says the environmental variables aren’t configured.
This is the code: https://github.com/fernandod1/Instagram-to-discord/blob/master/instagram-discord.py

And here’s mine (replaced the username with ‘instagram’ and webhook with discord.com to post on here):

```
INSTAGRAM_USERNAME = os.environ.get('instagram')

# ----------------------- Do not modify under this line ----------------------- #


def get_user_fullname(html):
    return html.json()["graphql"]["user"]["full_name"]


def get_total_photos(html):
    return int(html.json()["graphql"]["user"]["edge_owner_to_timeline_media"]["count"])


def get_last_publication_url(html):
    return html.json()["graphql"]["user"]["edge_owner_to_timeline_media"]["edges"][0]["node"]["shortcode"]


def get_last_photo_url(html):
    return html.json()["graphql"]["user"]["edge_owner_to_timeline_media"]["edges"][0]["node"]["display_url"]


def get_last_thumb_url(html):
    return html.json()["graphql"]["user"]["edge_owner_to_timeline_media"]["edges"][0]["node"]["thumbnail_src"]


def get_description_photo(html):
    return html.json()["graphql"]["user"]["edge_owner_to_timeline_media"]["edges"][0]["node"]["edge_media_to_caption"]["edges"][0]["node"]["text"]


def webhook(webhook_url, html):
    # for all params, see https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook
    # for all params, see https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object
    data = {}
    data["embeds"] = []
    embed = {}
    embed["color"] = 15467852
    embed["title"] = "New pic of @"+INSTAGRAM_USERNAME+""
    embed["url"] = "https://www.instagram.com/p/" + \
        get_last_publication_url(html)+"/"
    embed["description"] = get_description_photo(html)
    # embed["image"] = {"url":get_last_thumb_url(html)} # unmark to post bigger image
    embed["thumbnail"] = {"url": get_last_thumb_url(html)}
    data["embeds"].append(embed)
    result = requests.post(webhook_url, data=json.dumps(
        data), headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})
    try:
        result.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        print(err)
    else:
        print("Image successfully posted in Discord, code {}.".format(
            result.status_code))


def get_instagram_html(INSTAGRAM_USERNAME):
    headers = {
        "Host": "www.instagram.com",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11"
    }
    html = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/" +
                        INSTAGRAM_USERNAME + "/feed/?__a=1", headers=headers)
    return html

def main():
    try:
        html = get_instagram_html(INSTAGRAM_USERNAME)
        if(os.environ.get("LAST_IMAGE_ID") == get_last_publication_url(html)):
            print("Not new image to post in discord.")
        else:
            os.environ["LAST_IMAGE_ID"] = get_last_publication_url(html)
            print("New image to post in discord.")
            webhook(os.environ.get('https://discord.com/'),
                    get_instagram_html(INSTAGRAM_USERNAME))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if os.environ.get('instagram') != None and os.environ.get('https://discord.com/') != None:
        while True:
            main()
            time.sleep(float(os.environ.get('10') or 600)) # 600 = 10 minutes
    else:
        print('Please configure environment variables properly!')
```

It says that the environmental variables aren’t properly configured

Comment: `os.environ.get('https://discord.com/')` makes little sense, and `os.environ.get('10')` is most likely illegal in most shells; what actually are you trying to do?

Comment: Did you even try researching what [environment variables](https://developer.vonage.com/blog/21/10/01/python-environment-variables-a-primer#:~:text=What%20Are%20Environment%20Variables%3F,it%20connects%20to%20the%20API.) are?